# Type conversion and typeof

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have the following declaration in C#

```
private IDictionary<ViewModelBase, Type> _routingDictionary;
```

With the following method

```
public void Navigate<TDestinationViewModel>() where TDestinationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //I want to use something like
    var des = _routingDictionary[typeof(TDestinationViewModel)]
}
```

but this does not work and I get a compilation error

> Cannot convert from 'System.Type' to
>   'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase'

I can resolve this by using the following

```
public void Navigate<TDestinationViewModel>() where TDestinationViewModel : ViewModelBase, new()    
{
    TDestinationViewModel des = new TDestinationViewModel();
    Type destination = _routingDictionary[des];            

}
```

However istn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You defined a key of type ViewModelBase but then try to read with a key of type Type?

Answer (score 7):

You have declared the dictionary other way around. i.e `ViewModelBase` as a key and `Type` as a value.

It should be

```
private IDictionary<Type, ViewModelBase> _routingDictionary;
```

Which says that `Type` will be a key and `ViewModelBase` as a value.